# How to interpret MM_DD as time information for Altair graph?

Tags: python, pandas, date, altair

I am struggling to interpret a month and day (MMDD, or MM_DD in my case) info as "Time" in my Altair graph.

The data I am working with contains the daily level of a lake from year 1850 until today. I calculated the min, max, mean value for every individual day of the year (mm_dd). Then, I converted my data frame to a long format, which now looks like this:

| [] | mm_dd | value_type | levelcm | month |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 01_01 | value_min | 242 | 01 |
| 1 | 01_02 | value_min | 243 | 01 |
| 2 | 01_01 | value_mean | 301 | 01 |
| 3 | 01_02 | value_mean | 300 | 01 |
| 4 | 01_01 | value_max | 380 | 01 |
| 5 | 01_02 | value_max | 380 | 01 |

With

```
    alt.Chart(df_mmm_long).mark_line().encode(
      x='mm_dd',
      y='levelcm',
      color='value_type'
    )
```

I am getting

[altair_mm_dd](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xlxFH.png)

Ideally, I would like the line chart to be based on the mm_dd information, but have a monthly scale on the X-axis.

Answer (score 1):

If you change a type of the column with dates to datetime, Altair will nicely group labels for you. Here in my example I took Rhein data for the last 25 years or so... :

```
a=df_.groupby(["Month", "Tag"], as_index="False").agg(minimum = ('Level', 'min'), \
                                 average = ('Level', 'mean'),
                                 maximum = ('Level', 'max')).reset_index()#.transpose()


a.Month=a.Month.replace({'Januar':1, 'Februar':2, 'Maerz':3, 'April':4, 'Mai':5, 'Juni':6, 'Juli':7,
       'August':8, 'September':9, 'Oktober':10, 'November':11, 'Dezember':12})

#combine day and month to date column
a['date']=a.Tag.astype(str)+"/"+a.Month.astype(str)+"/2020"
a.date=pd.to_datetime(a['date'], errors='ignore')


alt.Chart(a).transform_fold(
['minimum', 'average', 'maximum']).mark_line().encode(
x=alt.X("date:T"), 
y=alt.Y("value:Q",),
color='key:N'
).properties(width=600)
```

still not the nicest chart and requires some work, but as a start)

I guess you will add a curent level for 2022, so it's fine if the column date is 2022. In your example - they also have a current year at the axes labels

[image]

link to the data - [Rhein data if someone wants to help](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ngolos/dataviz/main/rhein_96_22.csv)
P.S. Or you want a chart by month like that one (source:datawrapper)
[image]

Comment: Thank you for looking into this and your feedback.
Unfortunately, I am not sure how I can translate this to my use case.
You are right, what I try to achieve is similar to the "Rhine" use case. In fact, this is what I try to replicate in a first step:
https://www.hvz.baden-wuerttemberg.de/pegel.html?id=00007 (see 'Jahresgang').

Now, in order to get there, I need to get a dataframe with the max, min, mean value for every day of the year (MM_DD). This takes all the data from 1850 until today.
But what would the time field look like in this dataframe, so altair can interpret it correctly?

Comment: Understood, my suggestion is anyway to transfer this column to datetime column. I used 2020 for that, because I didn't want to fight with 29.2... I will update the code in my answer so that you could see the difference